# JQuery Success/Failure Callback is not called

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, web-services, jquery-callback

I am new at jQuery. What i need to achieve in jQuery is call a web service which is written in Python and show appropriate message according to the message i receive in return.
Below is the jQuery code i have written so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#loginForm").submit( function () { 
    data = $(this).serialize()
    var serviceUrl = MyServiceUrl;
    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: serviceUrl,
              data: data,
              success:loginSuccess,
              failure: loginFailure
    });   
    return false;   
});
});

function loginSuccess(data){
    alert(data.status);
}
function loginFailure(data){
    alert(data.status);
}
```

On my HTML form when i submit the form my call goes to my web service. But after recieving the response it does not go to my success or failure callback function as specified above. Below is the python code of the web service which is returning the status. It can either return case 1 or case 2

Case 1:

```
to_json = {"status": "success"}
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype="application/json")
```

Case 2:

```
to_json = {"status": "error","message": str(e)}
return HttpResponseBadRequest(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: hmm, should you call something like: success:loginSuccess(data)?

Comment: If i do that it calls the Success and failure function before sending the request to the webservice.. But does not go to success or failure once the response has been received..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

Below is my solution.

When returning from python i added the following headers

```
to_json = {"status": "success"}
response = HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype="application/json")
response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
return response
```

The same was with HttpResponseBadRequest.
So the final jQuery code is as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#loginForm").submit( function () { 
    data = $(this).serialize()
    var serviceUrl = MyServiceUrl;
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: serviceUrl,
          data: data,
          success:loginSuccess,
          error: loginFailure
    });   
    return false;   
 });
});

function loginSuccess(data){
    alert(data.status);
}
function loginFailure(data){
    alert(data.status);
}
```

I hope it really helps someone..Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Remove submit form, use ajax only

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#your_button_id").click( function () { 
       data = $("#loginForm").serialize()
       var serviceUrl = MyServiceUrl;
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: serviceUrl,
          data: data,
          success:loginSuccess(),
          failure: loginFailure()
       });   
       return false;   
   });
});
```

Comment: When you use "$("#loginForm").submit", it means your form was submited, therefore, the ajax call is used after it, you should change your button to type non-submit

Comment: what happen when you use my answer?

Comment: I am now trying to debug the code using firebug.. I am getting following exception XMLHttpRequest cannot load ''. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: try use dataType: 'json'

Comment: or check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-w